# subsequence example2

Tags: real-analysis

In the textbook, there is a question about whether or not a sequence that does not converge to 42 and yet have infinitely many terms of the sequence equal to 42.

I am having a hard time coming up with examples of such sequences, and so need some hints to help me think clearly.

Comment: Think about having half of the terms be $42$ and the other half (say)...

Comment: Can you not think for yourself? You have asked three simple questions about sequences in the past half an hour and have yet to acknowledge the answers given to you...

Comment: 42,0,42,0,42,0,...

Comment: Well, I am trying to.

Comment: @fretty And thanks for helping me.

Comment: {$a_n$} = 42sin(n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let

$$a_n=\left\{\begin{array}{rcl} 5 & \mbox{if} &n \text{ is odd}, \\ 42 & \mbox{if} & n \text{ is even}. \end{array} \right.$$

Comment: Could you please give an explanation of your example? I don't get it.

Comment: This sequence oscillates between $5$ and $42$: $a_1 =5, a_2=42, a_3=5, a_4=42, \ldots$

Comment: Wow. I don't have any idea on how to come up with it's formula.

Comment: You don't need to have a formula. Just think of the sequence as $(5,42,5,42,...)$.

Comment: Well, for me the formula actually makes more sense that a sequence itself.

Comment: $a_n$ = $5n + 42n^2$?

Comment: What is $a_1$ for that formula? is it $5$ as it should be?

Comment: No lol. That was stupid. I'll think and then write.

Comment: A sequence is a function from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb R$, you can define functions by parts as I just defined the $a_n$'s, saying what is the value of the function for each $n \in \Bbb N$, which can be an odd or even number. As I already told you, the formula is not necessary. It's absolutely correct to define sequences like that.

Comment: Yes, but how do you know that the sequence oscillates between 5 and 42 without knowing the function?

Comment: That the sequence oscillates means that it alternates, taking only these two values consecutively. If you want to know the formula so bad, it can be $a_n=[1-(-1)^n]\cdot \frac{5}{2}+[1+(-1)^{n}]\cdot \frac{42}{2}$, but I don't think it will help you in anything. It will only make the problem more difficult for you.